# remove drag and drop objects when exit frame on button click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop, flash-cs5

i want to make flash application that allowed users to match picture with the box containing its first letter of the word. the method is drag and drop with target. i'm really new to this.

drag and drop target is working so far but my problem is when i exit the frame after moving the object, the drag and drop object still visible.

how can i remove this object when leaving frame?

here is what i got:

```js
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

var objectoriginalX:Number;
var objectoriginalY:Number;

a.buttonMode = true;
a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);       

function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 event.target.startDrag();
 event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
 objectoriginalX = event.target.x;
 objectoriginalY = event.target.y;
}

function dropObject(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 event.target.stopDrag();
 var matchingTargetName:String = "target" + event.target.name;
 var matchingTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(matchingTargetName);
 if(event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == matchingTarget)
 {
  event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
  event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
  event.target.buttonMode = false;
  event.target.x = matchingTarget.x;
  event.target.y = matchingTarget.y;
 }
 else
 {
  event.target.x = objectoriginalX;
  event.target.y = objectoriginalY;
 }
}
```

thanks before, any suggestion will be appreciated

edited: this is the code i use to move to other scene

```js
HOME1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_15);

function fl_ClickToGoToScene_15(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndStop(2, "Scene 1");
}
```

Comment: how do you move on to the next frame?  when you use `addChild` to parent or reparent an object, you need to use `removeChild` to get rid of it.   Once reparented (if originally parented on the timeline), the timeline will no longer affect an object.  Looks like all you probably need to do is clear all children manually before moving on to the next frame  `removeChildren();  nextFrame();`.

Comment: I try to use button click to move on the next frame. And i already tried using removeChildren(); but it gives me an error 1180:call to a possibly undefined method removeChildren. Really need help here. Thanks.

Comment: You need to show your relevant code.  Update your question and include the code you're using to go to the next frame.

Comment: thanks for the reply, already update and include the code i use to go to other scene. really appreciate your help.

Comment: removeChildren only works in Flash Player 11 or later.  What version are you outputting?

Comment: it's flash player 10. there is no flash player 11 in the publish setting. Is this means i need to update first?

Comment: I updated my answer a few hours ago to show how to remove all children without using `removeChildren()`.    While upgrading would be nice to utilize features added since FP10 (current version is 20), it's not required to do what you want to do.

Comment: Did you get it figured out Daniel?

Answer (score 0):

When through code you do something to a timeline object that causes the parentage to change,   that timeline object will no longer be controlled by the timeline.

So when you do this:

```
event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
```

(presumably to bring the item being dragged to the front), you are inadvertently telling Flash that this object is controlled by code now.

The solution, is to manually remove the object(s) by code when done with them. This can be done with `removeChild(childObject)`.

Since you are likely dealing with multiple objects that can be dragged around, it would likely be easiest to just clear all children manually prior to going to the next frame:

```
removeChildren(); //remove all children of the current context (timeline)
nextFrame(); //go to the next frame,  or play(); or whatever you want to do
```

If you are targeting an older version of flash (less than 11 doesn't support the `removeChildren` method), you can do this in it's place:

```
var i:int = numChildren;
while(i--){
    removeChildAt(i);
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't desire to clear all children of the current timeline, you could just keep track of what's being dragged around and remove those object:

```
var draggedObjs:Array = [];
function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    draggedObjs.push(event.target);
    ...rest of code
```

Then do this when ready to move on:

```
for each(obj in draggedObjs){
    removeChild(obj);
}
draggedObjs = [];

nextFrame(); //or whatever
```

Another option, would be to duplicate the item clicked, add it to stage, then drag the duplicate and match the originals position to it on mouse move.  When the drag is done, remove the duplicate from stage.